# How to combine two hazard ratios from the study for a meta-analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis, hazard

I've been searching for a way to combine two hazard ratios from the same study for a meta-analysis, but found nothing. Does anyone know how to do this?

Any thoughts would be great.

Good Day,

Simon

Comment: Hi everybody,

I've been searching for a way to combine two hazard ratios from the same study for a meta-analysis, but found nothing. Does anyone know how to do so ?

Any thoughts would be grate.

Good Day,

Simon

Answer (score 3):

Hazard ratios can be combined if you have their 95% confidence intervals.

For instance, in Stata, using the user command `metan` (type `findit metan` from within Stata if you don't already have it), you can use the following code in a do file to check out how the HRs can be combined:

```
clear all

input str6 trialname hr ll ul
    Trial1 0.7 .46 1.08
    Trial2 1.05 .82 1.34
    end

metan hr ll ul, effect(Hazard Ratio) null(1) xlabel(0, .5, 1, 1.5) ///
lcols(trialname) texts(200) force
```

Which gives the following output as well as a forest plot:

```
               Study     |     ES    [95% Conf. Interval]     % Weight
---------------------+---------------------------------------------------
Trial1               |  0.700       0.460     1.080         41.30
Trial2               |  1.050       0.820     1.340         58.70
---------------------+---------------------------------------------------
I-V pooled ES        |  0.905       0.706     1.105        100.00
---------------------+---------------------------------------------------
 Heterogeneity calculated by formula
  Q = SIGMA_i{ (1/variance_i)*(effect_i - effect_pooled)^2 } 
where variance_i = ((upper limit - lower limit)/(2*z))^2 

  Heterogeneity chi-squared =   2.87 (d.f. = 1) p = 0.090
  I-squared (variation in ES attributable to heterogeneity) =  65.2%

  Test of ES=0 : z=   8.91 p = 0.000
```

[image]

I hope this helps. If you don't use Stata, I'm sure any stats package can do a similar thing if you adapt the code.

Comment: Nice answer, but one caveat: The OP said that the two hazard ratios came from the same study. If that means that the two HRs were calculated based on the same sample of subjects (or at least overlapping groups to some extent), then the two HRs cannot be assumed to be independent (which the method described above assumes).

Comment: That is true, but if they're from the same study, he's got all the data and presumably could calculate an overall HR primarily. To the OP: why do you need to combine HRs from the same study?

Comment: (OP) it's for a meta-analysis. Let's say I have 10 hazard ratio. 8 of them are global HR from 8 differents studies. The last 2 are from the same study. I can't use the global HR because there's one category of more comparatively of the others studies.

Comment: (I don't have the raw data)

Comment: It's not safe to assume you can just calculate an overall HR. Sub-group or stratified reporting is pretty common. @user6101 Do the authors of the study give any information about how the HRs were obtained? Did they stratify the analysis, or is this the output of a regression model. If they literally split their population, it's pretty common to treat them as two separate studies.

Comment: @Epigrad :

The study is about smoking. So the reference category is non-smoker and there's 3 categories to compare with : ex smoker, <10 cig per day and more then 10 per day. 

But in the others studies I don't have the ex smoker cateogry.

(Thanks for you help everyone btw !)

Comment: @user6101 If you're interested in comparing across studies, why not just toss the one category that's not reported elsewhere? It's unfortunate, and I'd note it in the paper itself, but there's no real reason to retain it if there's nothing its being compared to in the other studies.

Comment: @Epigrad : That's where we are leading on. So if we just combine the HRs, do you know a formula to combine the HRs with only the HRs, n and des C.I. ?

Comment: @user6101 This should be a function of almost *any* meta-analysis package you are using. Do you have an idea which software you'll be doing this with?

Comment: Yes. Revman 5. Do you know which option should I use ?

Comment: And if I use random effects instead of combining the studies ?

Comment: @Epigrad :  
Yes. Revman 5. Do you know which option should I use ?

Comment: @Epigrad : And if I use random effects instead of combining the studies ?

Comment: @user6101 Unfortunately, I've never touched Revman. And random effects (presumably versus a fixed effects model) will still combine the studies, there's just a difference in how the underlying distributions are handled - its possible to still get a single summary estimate.

Comment: this method is no correct. you have to transfer HR to lnHR, and UL, LL of lnHR. Because 95%CI in this case is for continuous data only, and could have calculated the wrong weight for each trial.