# Hazard Ratio Meta-Analysis

Tags: survival, stata, meta-analysis, proportional-hazards

I've being reading around the forum and couldn't find exactly what I wanted.

I am trying to do an meta-analysis where the HR of each study and the 95% CI were available. I understand variance can be estimated from the confidence intervals, and this can be enough to pool a HR meta-analysis.

But I am struggling with the coding, in SPSS and R, and I was wondering whether someone could point me into a right direction with a worked example perhaps in STATA.

I had look at this code:
[How to combine two hazard ratios from the study for a meta-analysis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15025/how-to-combine-two-hazard-ratios-from-the-study-for-a-meta-analysis)

I tried to run it, but it did not work in STATA for me. The metan command came up with the error of not enough variables. Could someone give me some guidance here?

Comment: You would probably be better on Statalist where you would need to show them what you did as telling them just the error message is unlikely to be enough. If you want coding help in R try the https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis// mailing list and show the code and any error you get. You need to register for the R list.

Answer (score 4):

In terms of doing this in R, the link https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2014-November/423617.html gives an example on how to log-transform the hazard ratios and compute their standard errors in preparation for the meta-analysis, which I borrowed from for the R code below:

```
### specify hazard ratios (hr)
hr    <- c(3.12, 1.15)
### specify lower bound for hr confidence intervals 
ci.lb <- c(2.2, 1.03)
### specify upper bound for hr confidence intervals 
ci.ub <- c(4.1, 2.6)

### log-transform hazard ratios and compute standard error 
### based on the confidence interval bounds 

yi  <- log(hr) 
sei  <- (log(ci.ub) - log(ci.lb)) / (2*1.96)

### store yi and sei in a data set 
dat <- data.frame(yi=yi, sei=sei)

### add trial number and author
trial <- 1:2 
author <- c("Anderson 2015", "Borenstein 2017")

dat <- cbind.data.frame(trial=trial, author=author, dat)
```

Now that you have yi and sei, you are ready to do your meta-analysis with the metafor package using a fixed-effects model:

```
 install.packages("metafor")

 library(metafor)

 res <- rma(yi, sei=sei, data=dat, method="FE")

 ### for a random effects model, could use:
 ### res <- rma(yi, sei=sei, data=dat, method="REML")

 summary(res)

 forest(res)

 funnel(res)
```

This should be enough to get you started. See the link below for more details about the metafor package: 
http://www.edii.uclm.es/~useR-2013/Tutorials/kovalchik/kovalchik_meta_tutorial.pdf.